# BO and DAO in Spring + JSF

Tags: spring, jsf, javabeans, communication, dao

I have a architecture dillema. I've implemented Bean (@Named) BO and DAO. And I am not sure how communication should be implemented. Let's say I want to register user. I am filling the bean from JSF then I use userBO.registerUser(this) method on injected userBO. I am not sure what should happen next. I think validation should be BO's work and if everything is ok data should be passed to DAO. DAO should create UserEntity and persist it into database. But what if we create UserEntity in BO and pass it to DAO. I am a little bit confused.

Comment: Are you using JDBC or JPA? JPA is at its own already the DAO layer.

Comment: jpa but still I should be able to get elements from database by id or smth like this in the future

Answer (score 0):

BO should deal with any business logic.

If the creation of the UserEntity is related with any business logic (i.e. the attributes or the values need to be calculated according to a non-trivial logic rule) the creation might stay in the BO. If the creation is simple, and basically puts the values of the form in the object, it can be populated in a previous layer (Controller, or JSF, or whatever).

About the DAO, it should only persist a populated object into your database.

Hope this helps you!